# ClassifierFunction::mlbddataev: The data being evaluated is not formatted correctly

Tags: import, machine-learning

I am trying to run the `NearestNeighbor` classifier on the [wisc_bc_data.csv](https://github.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/blob/master/wisc_bc_data.csv) dataset as follows:

```
data = 
  SemanticImport[
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-\
     datasets/master/wisc_bc_data.csv"];

c1 = 
  Classify[
    data[
      All, 
      {"diagnosis", "radius_mean", "texture_mean", "perimeter_mean"}] -> "diagnosis", 
    "NearestNeighbor"]
```

However Mathematica complains:

> ClassifierFunction::mlbddataev: The data being evaluated is not formatted correctly

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape of the output let's you know what's going wrong:

```
ClassifierFunction[...]["NearestNeighbor", ...]
```

So, `Classify` has evaluated returning a `ClassifierFunction` which is then being applied to `"NearestNeighbor"` as if it were data as it is another form of `Classify`. But, that clearly does not have the right shape to be used by the `ClassifierFunction`, so you get a message telling you this. To use a different classification method, you need to set the `Method` option, e.g.

```
dataset= data[All, {"diagnosis", "radius_mean", "texture_mean", "perimeter_mean"}];
Classify[dataset -> "diagnosis", Method -> "NearestNeighbors"]
```